# Deleting a backbone collection both from the view and the server

Tags: backbone.js, collections, coffeescript

Struggling to make the following code work in a view that manages a backbone collection:

```
class VGStream.Views.Scenarios.ScheduleRisks extends Backbone.View
  template: JST['backbone/templates/scenarios/schedule_risks']

  initialize: (options) ->
    super
    Backbone.pubsub.on 'allSchedulesRemoved', @removeAllScheduleRisks, @

  removeAllScheduleRisks: =>
    for risk in @risks.models
      risk.destroy
    @render()

  render: ->
    super
    @risks.fetch()
    @$el.html @template @
    @
```

I am just showing the relevant code snippet from the Coffeescript class view.  This does not delete the 'risk' models either from the database or the list view itself.  How should I do it?  The event allSchedulesRemoved fires correctly when all schedules are removed.  I want the associated risks to be removed as well from both the view as well as the database.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't always have to call `super`
2. There are built-in `@risks.each()` method to loop through collections.
3. Put `fetch()` in `render()` is not recommended.
4. To clear the collection, you could do several `@risks.remove(risk)` or, after destroyed everything, `reset` the collection with an empty object.
5. `risk.destroy` actually send a delete request to your backend, so whether it's deleted in server or not depends on your backend code.